# how to use page function in user control

Tags: asp.net

I have an GridView and in GridView template field i used a user control.
in the user control their is data list.

in my parent page their is BindGrid function. i want to call BindGrid function of page inside Datalist_RowCommand event.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you create an event in your user control which the parent page subscribes to.

Then in the Datalist_RowCommand call (fire) the event.  A method (event handler) in the parent page will then recieve information from the control and you can call your function from there.